# python ordereddict: access certain depth within dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a function which takes a dict and prints it's content in a nice sexy way.

I would like to edit the function to control the depth of the dict but I'm kind of lost.

here is the function:

```
def print_dict(_dict, indent=""):
    for k, v in _dict.items():
        if hasattr(v, 'items'):
            print "%s(%s::" % (indent, k)
            print_dict(v, indent + "  ")
            print "%s)" % indent
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            print "%s(%s::" % (indent, k)
            for i in v:
                print_dict(dict(i), indent + "  ")
            print "%s)" % indent
       else:
            print "%s(%s::%s)" % (indent, k, v)
```

output:

```
(Axis::
  (@Name::kfcQ1[{kfcQ1_1}].kfcQ1_grid)
  (@MdmName::kfcQ1[{kfcQ1_1}].kfcQ1_grid)
  (@UseMetadataDefinition::true)
  (@Label::kfcQ1_1. Veuillez sélectionner votre réponse)
  (Labels::
    (Label::
      (@Language::FRA)
      (@Text::kfcQ1_1. Veuillez sélectionner votre réponse?)
    )
  )
  (Elements::
    (Element::
      (Style::None)
      (@Name::UnweightedBase)
      (@MdmName::)
      (@IsHiddenWhenColumn::true)
      (Labels::
        (Label::
          (@Language::FRA)
          (@Text::Base brute)
        )
      )
    )   
)
```

desired output

```
print_dict(_dict, depth=0, indent="")
(Axis::
  (@Name::kfcQ1[{kfcQ1_1}].kfcQ1_grid)
  (@MdmName::kfcQ1[{kfcQ1_1}].kfcQ1_grid)
  (@UseMetadataDefinition::true)
  (@Label::kfcQ1_1. Veuillez sélectionner votre réponse)
)
```

Really hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please show the `_dict` you are passing to this function ?

Comment: You could initialize a variable called `depth` and change it's value every time your function gets called and you could check the value of `depth` every time at the start of the function, as you do in a classic recursive program ? **Base case** if I get more technical in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the signature of your function so that it accepts two new parameters: `depth` and `max_depth`:

```
def print_dict(_dict, indent="", depth=0, max_depth=-1):
```

Before each call to `print_dict`, increment depth:

```
print_dict(v, indent + "  ", depth=depth + 1, max_depth=max_depth)
print_dict(dict(i), indent + "  ", depth=depth + 1, max_depth=max_depth)
```

Finally, at the start of the function, check `depth` against `max_depth`:

```
def print_dict(_dict, indent="", depth=0, max_depth=-1):
    if max_depth > 0 and depth > max_depth:
        return
```

Comment: Beautiful! thanks a lot for this, it was a bit beyond my comprehension!